# Android Kotlin calendar , how to open a new activity when double click a day of calendar

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a calendar and what I want is when I double click a certain day, a new activity should open.
I know, I have no code provided but all I want from the calendar is to open a new activity. Yes I know how to open a new activity with a button for example but could not manage to get this one done.

I have been looking for an answer for hours and still did not find one.

Comment: There is no built-in double-click listener for the Android CalendarView widget. However, you can implement your own double-click listener by using the GestureDetector class in combination with the OnDateChangeListener of the CalendarView.

Comment: Not an answer, but this sounds like very frustrating UI to use. It's very hard to "double-click" a tiny button on a touch screen, and calendar buttons are tiny.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved can you please give me a simple example, I will be thankful to you forever

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right, but I need it for an app that tracks time

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for anyone who is interested , NewDataActivity is the activity I want to move to when I double-click the calendar view, for better code please correct me, my code looks like this:

```
val calendarView = findViewById<CalendarView>(R.id.calendarView)
    var lastClickTime = 0L

    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
        val clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA) {
            // Double-click detected
            val intent = Intent(this, NewDataActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            // Single-click detected
            println("")
        }

        lastClickTime = clickTime
    }
}

companion object {
    const val DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300 // milliseconds
}
```